# Speed reduction in wifi mesh

Tags: networking, wifi

Recently we configured a Wifi mesh system in our office. Initially, without the mesh system we achieved 95Mbps speed but after we prepared 3 devices for the mesh system speed reduced to 75-80 Mbps. Due to network outages we brought in 3 more mesh devices and connected them to the existing mesh network (total 6). Surprisingly achieved speed reduced again to 40-45 Mbps. We tested from all nodes and got same result.

For testing we removed 3 mesh nodes and the speed gain back to 75-80 Mbps.

So does adding more nodes in Mesh network distribute the available network speed equally across the network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More correctly, adding more nodes uses up channel bandwidth, which decreases your throughput.